# How to read shell commands documentation in android

Tags: shell, terminal

I have busybox installed in phone. Also, my device is rooted. I tried to use man command:

```
$ man ls
```

However, it returns no manual entry for 'ls'. I tried to navigate to /bin/busybox but there is no directory named /bin. What is it that I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `busybox man ls` ?

Comment: Yes same result no entry for ls found

Comment: How about `busybox ls --help` ? Also check if busybox installed to `system/xbin`

Comment: Are you certain there exists a manpage for `ls` in your system? Busybox keeps space in mind, so it is obvious it wouldn't be coming with man pages of most of the utilities. Also, unlike a traditional Linux, the equivalent of `/bin` is `/system/bin` but busybox keeps the utilities and itself in `/system/xbin`.